# Numba vectorize not working properly on a simple example

Tags: pycharm, gpu, vectorization, numba

I'm trying to add gpu support for a program I'm working on and came across numba and cuda and then ufunc. I am going through the basic example from https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/ufunc.html
I'm using pycharm 2019.3.1
I'm using numba 0.51.2

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): line 19, in <module>
D = cu_discriminant(A, B, C)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Not sharing path for obvious reasons
Is this a problem with my code or a numba problem?

Here is my code:

```
import math
from numba import vectorize
import numpy as np
from time import perf_counter as count
Start = count()

@vectorize(['float32(float32, float32, float32)',
        'float64(float64, float64, float64)'],
       target='cpu')
def cu_discriminant(a, b, c):
    return math.sqrt(b ** 2 - 4 * a * c)

N = 10000
dtype = np.float32

# prepare the input
A = np.array(np.random.sample(N), dtype=dtype)
B = np.array(np.random.sample(N) + 10, dtype=dtype)
C = np.array(np.random.sample(N), dtype=dtype)

D = cu_discriminant(A, B, C)

print(D)  # print result
Stop = count()
print(f'it took {round(Stop - Start, 3)} seconds')
```

It works when target = 'cpu' but not when target='cuda'

I'm at a loss as to what to do because my code would be greatly speed up by GPU acceleration. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What GPU, CUDA, and Python version are you using? Perhaps more generally, your error isn't necessarily coming from Numba. It's a generic Python error. The reason I mention both of these is that your code runs fine on my machine (Python 3.7, CUDA 10.2, V100 GPU, Numba 0.51.2).

Comment: 2080, I dont think I know how to install cuda properly I have the vs code written in c. Python 3.7.

Comment: What does `nvidia-smi` typed at the terminal show you?

Answer (score -1):

Your code works well without 'tensorflow 2' on both case.

The results are as below

in case of "target='cpu'"
[10.905523 10.944542 10.116297 ... 10.752323 10.669133 10.494761]
it took 0.083 seconds

in case of "target='cuda'"
[10.605754 10.977879 10.845842 ... 10.56295  10.10678  10.774803]
it took 0.129 seconds

```
# with rtx 3070
```

But i've found same errors where the 'tensorflow 2' was installed.
The error message is "NvvmError: Failed to compile"

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer. Please check on how to write awesome answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer